# How to add output of our loop into new column in our dataset in R?

Tags: r, loops

I want to add the output of the loop in a new column "Compared_data".

Data set is libraries_four.

```
for (i in 1:20)
  
{
    if ((Libraries_four[i,"PhyloAlps_iden"] == 1) & (Libraries_four[i,"ArctBorBryo_iden"] == 1 |
       Libraries_four[i,"EMBL_143_iden"] == 1 | Libraries_four[i,"PhyloNorway_iden"] == 1 )) 
    { 
      print(TRUE)
    } 
    else 
    { 
      print(FALSE)
    }

}
```

The code is working fine but I tried the `mutate` function for the new column but it is not working. Is there any other way to add a new variable/column?

Comment: "it is not working" isn't helpful to anyone. Please share a sample of your data using ``dput(head(Libraries_four))`` and the exact error message you have.

Answer (score 1):

R is vectorised language, you would rarely need an explicit `for` loop. Try this :

```
library(dplyr)

Libraries_four <- Libraries_four %>%
                     mutate(result = PhyloAlps_iden == 1 & ArctBorBryo_iden == 1|
                                     EMBL_143_iden == 1 | PhyloNorway_iden == 1)
```

This would create a new column called `result` in `Libraries_four` dataset.

You can also do this in base R :

```
Libraries_four <- transform(Libraries_four, result = PhyloAlps_iden == 1 & ArctBorBryo_iden == 1 | EMBL_143_iden == 1 | PhyloNorway_iden == 1)
```

Comment: Thank you for the information, I wanted to add the results of each loop into new column, Will this new code written by will also add output of the each loop into the new column ?

Comment: No, this will add a single column `result` to your original daraframe `Libraries_four`. Maybe I have misunderstood what you are looking for.